# Reworking loop in Python

Tags: python

I have a Python loop that looks like this:

```
for i in range(n):
   if (status[i]==-1):
      <main code>
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this - some kind of "where" in the iterator?

The code runs as expected, it is just inefficient and slow. If I have 200000 records and only 30 of them have a status[i]==-1, I don't want to examine all 200000.

Comment: How can you know their status without examining them?

Comment: How do you know it's inefficient and slow? How fast does it need to be? There's a difference between being slow and taking a long time.

Comment: one for-loop is `O(N)` since you have 200000 records it is taking time. Even if you sort them it will take `O(NlogN)` time.

Comment: What is `status`? It's odd that you are using a range and then accessing status by index. I can't help but feel that this is an XY problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterating a Python list is inherently slow. Try some vectorization library as *numpy*, which is implemented in C and can perform operations like this several hundred times faster. E.g.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(status)
x = np.where(arr == -1)

print(x)
```

Comment: What's the timing?

Answer (score 2):

```
for s in status:
    if(s == -1):
```

This will look better for sure, and may be slightly more efficient.

Comment: I agree that it looks better, but it is not more efficient.